# Using modulo division expression in angular 2

Tags: angular, expression, ng-class

I have a requirement to use modulo division in angular 2 HTML template. So, I couldn't find anything related to modulo division in Angular 2 Docs for expressions. So, is there any ways to meet my requirement?

Here what I wanna do.
Adding a class(color code) according to the index.

```
[ngClass]="{'color0': i===0, 'color1': i===1, 'color2': i===2, 'color3': i===3, 'color4': i===4, 'color5': i===5, 'color6': i===6, 'color7': i===7, 'color8': i===8, 'color9': i===9}"
```

**In this way after 9th index I can't get a color.** And, adding more classes will make the line longer.

Comment: you can use also `[ngClass]="'color'+(i%10)"`, is using ngClass with `stringExp` (a expresion that return an string), see the differents ways of using ngClass in https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass. NOTE %NUM gets the values 0 to NUM-1

Answer (score 1):

In you're component class add:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.colors = ["color0", "color1", "color2", ........];
}
```

and in the template, change to:

```
[ngClass]="colors[i]"
```

Comment: @Douenias Thanks. This is helpful to make the life shorter as... Smart. But my requirement is if there's an index of 11 I should be able to apply the color code.
Don't know the reason why? and who added the downvote. Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i don't understand very well, but you can put this logic on ngClass like this:

```
[ngClass]="( i % 2 === 0 ) ? 'blue' : 'red' "
```

With that, all multiple of two will have blue color and all multiple of three will have red color.

Maybe this example can help you to improve your logic.